# Can't mount newly generated Rails engine in an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-engines, rails-models

I have a complex Rails app and I want to extract some core functionality into an engine so that I can reuse the models etc in other Rails apps.

I've been following the official documentation for engines (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). I'm able to create a new engine inside the app and generate some test models

```
> rails plugin new testengine --mountable

testengine> rails generate model Test
```

This is the *.gemspec*

```
require_relative "lib/testengine/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name        = "testengine"
  spec.version     = Testengine::VERSION
  spec.authors     = ["Me"]
  spec.summary     = "testengine"

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"

  spec.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "Rakefile", "README.md"]

  spec.add_dependency "rails", "~> 6.1.4"
end
```

I console into the test dummy rails app in *testengine*, and I can find my new model at `Testengine::Test`, no problem. So far so good.

Now I get to section **4.1 Mounting the Engine**. I add the engine via the *Gemfile* file (in fact this is already done for me thanks to the rails generator above).

```
gem 'testengine', path: 'testengine'
```

Then I install my gems without problems.

```
> bundle install
...
Using testengine 0.1.0 from source at `testengine`
...
```

I console into the main app and I can find `Testengine` and `Testengine::VERSION` but not `Testengine::Engine` or `Testengine::Test`.

Reading a little further the docs say you need add this line to *config/routes.rb*

```
mount Testengine::Engine, at: "/testengine"
```

I do and now the rails app won't even start

```
config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Testengine::Engine (NameError)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: did you run `bundle` after adding the engine in  Gemfile?

Comment: yes. I edited my question to add that detail.

Comment: where is the engine located in the file system? From your question it looks as if it's under Rails.root, alongside app, config etc. Normally if it's mounted in the app, it's located under vendor/gems/. Alternatively, it could be mounted outside of Rails.root, if it's under development and not yet bundle-installable from github or rubygems.

Comment: ```rails plugin new testengine --mountable``` was executed inside the root directory of the app. The rails generator placed it in a folder called ```testengine``` in the the root directory of the app. This is a development environment. Moving this folder somewhere else doesn't solve the issue. For now I am leaving it in the root folder to try to a out-of-the-box installation. Furthermore, I can see and access changes I make to the /lib folder of the engine by using ```require 'enginetest'``` from within the app. My problem is nothing in the engine's app folder is loaded or accessible.

Comment: I just tried this on a Rails 6.1.4.1 app generated with the default settings and I can't reproduce the problem. `Testengine::Engine` is found without a hitch. I would try the classic steps of killing spring and checking for any autoloader issues.

Comment: Well after several hours of trying to try to pair down gems, I realized the ```gem 'testengine', path: 'testengine'``` was placed in a group that was not the same as the environment I was running my console in. I guess I incorrectly assumed that the gem was loaded because I could find Testengine without requiring it, even though it was in a different group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question for the benefit of others who might make the same mistake I made. In my case, `gem 'testengine', path: 'testengine'` was buried inside a group of gems e.g. in

```
group :test do
    ...
end
```

I guess I was confused how rails loads gems from groups and missed the detail about group inclusion. It seems that while it'll show in the list during `bundle install`, and autoload some basic items, such as `Testengine::VERSION` it doesn't autoload everything unless you are running an environment as the same name as the group. In hindsight, this seems a bit obvious. Lesson learned.